# Change the tint of the compoundDrawable right of EditText based on focus states

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-styles

I have been trying to figure out how to change the tint of a compoundDrawable of an EditText for some time with no success. I am using the EditText as a button and would like to change the color of the drawable right like the EditText underline color. How do I add a drawable state to the compoundDrawables?

I would like to tint the drawable like the underline tint when clicked.

Here is my styles.

```
<style name="EditTextDropdown" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">false</item>
    <item name="android:focusableInTouchMode">true</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:cursorVisible">false</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:drawableRight">@drawable/ic_drop_down_arrow_24dp</item>
</style>
```

EditText

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/phone"
    style="@style/EditTextDropdown"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Add phone" />
```

Here is what it looks like normal

[image: Normal]

Here is what it looks like when pressed

[image: Pressed]

Answer (score 0):

you can directly override the appearance of the `EditText` by re-assigning it's attributes in the `style` of the `Theme` you are using in your app.

given code overrides the `EditText` Appearance.

```
    <item name="android:editTextBackground">
        @drawable/myenglishviolettheme_edit_text_holo_light
    </item>
```

and the file in `drawable` is something like this `myenglishviolettheme_edit_text_holo_light.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/myenglishviolettheme_textfield_default_holo_light" />
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/myenglishviolettheme_textfield_disabled_holo_light" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/myenglishviolettheme_textfield_activated_holo_light" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/myenglishviolettheme_textfield_focused_holo_light" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/myenglishviolettheme_textfield_default_holo_light" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/myenglishviolettheme_textfield_disabled_focused_holo_light" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/myenglishviolettheme_textfield_disabled_holo_light" />
</selector>
```

You may want to change the `drawable` resources to match your requirement